# php, проверка на повторение события ближайшие 24 часа

Tags: php, дата

В моем телеграм боте есть функционал для отмены записи. Я сохраняю в отдельную таблицу время, когда запись была отменена, айди пользователя и самой записи.

Мне нужно сделать такую проверку - если за последние 24 часа один пользователь делал отмену более двух раз, (т.е. на третий раз) нужно кидать предупреждение. Не пойму как правильно эту проверку сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам надо знать делал ли пользователь отмену более двух раз, то очевидно надо считать отмены. Если я правильно понял, у вас есть таблица в бд, где вы записываете отмены.

Посчитайте отмены пользователя (для начала все, так проще). Думаю, у вас получится запрос типа такого `select count(*) from cancels where userId = :userId`. Осталось немного доработать запрос, чтобы считать отмены только за последние сутки. Вы храните время отмены, так что достаточно просто добавить условие, что время отмены больше чем (сейчас - 24 часа).

Ну а когда у вас будет количество отмен пользователя за последние сутки, просто сравните это число с вашим ограничением.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я что-то не подумала, что можно написать такое условие в запросе, вылетело из головы